# Debugging with GDB - seeing code around a given breakpoint

Tags: debugging, emacs, gdb, breakpoints

I am trying to debug a C++ program using GDB. I have set 15 breakpoints. Most of the breakpoints are in different files. After the first 5 breakpoints, it became difficult to remember what line of code any given breakpoint refers to.

I struggle quite a bit simply trying to recall what a given breakpoint refers to. I find this quite distracting. I was wondering if there is a way to tell gdb to display code around a certain breakpoint.

Something like this - `$(gdb) code 3` shows 30 lines of code around breakpoint 3. Is this possible today. Could you please show me how?

I run gdb in tui mode, and I also keep emacs open to edit my source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it exactly like this in gdb as such, but it can be scripted in gdb python.

This crude script should help:

```
import gdb

class Listbreak (gdb.Command):
        """ listbreak n Lists code around breakpoint """

        def __init__ (self):
                super(Listbreak, self).__init__ ("listbreak", gdb.COMMAND_DATA)

        def invoke (self, arg, from_tty):
                printed = 0
                for bp in gdb.breakpoints():
                        if bp.number == int(arg[0]):
                                printed = 1
                                print ("Code around breakpoint " + arg[0] + " (" + bp.location + "):")
                                gdb.execute("list " + bp.location)
                if printed == 0:
                        print ("No such breakpoint")
Listbreak()
```

Copy this to listbreak.py, source it in gdb (source listbreak.py), then use it like this:

listbreak 2

Answer (score 4):

You can use gdb within emacs.

In emacs, type `M-x gdb`, after entering the name of the executable, type `M-x gdb-many-windows`. It brings up an IDE-like interface, with access to debugger, locals, source, input/output, stack frame and breakpoints.

You can find a reference and snapshot [here](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/02/fancy-debugging-with-gdb.html).